# How to output a list by the results of two columns

Tags: mysql

I’ve a database where I store each product submitted by the curators, and there I register if it was approved. I need to generate a list where I show their score, ordered by the one who has more submitted (`subm`) and approved (`appr`). For that I need to get the approval rate (with the division of `appr/subm`) and we call it `ar` (Approval rate), and then I need a second operation to get the `cs` (Curator Score), which is the result of `appr*(ar*ar)`.

The final output should be as the following:

```
| Curator | subm  | appr|   ar   |     cs      |
------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 21    | 20  | 95.24% | 18.14058957 |
| 4       | 13    | 12  | 92.31% | 10.22485207 |
| 2       | 10    |  7  | 70.00% |  3.43       |
| 3       |  2    |  2  |100.00% |  2          |
```

To get the values from the table I  use

```
SELECT curator, SUM(prop) subm, SUM(date) appr
FROM control
GROUP BY curator
ORDER BY cs
```

But I need to add somewhere:

```
SUM(appr/subm) ar, SUM(appr*(ar*ar)) cs
```

But I don’t know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simplest to use your existing query as a subquery:

```
SELECT *, appr/subm AS ar, appr*(appr/subm*appr/subm)) AS cs 
FROM (SELECT curator, SUM(prop) subm, SUM(date) appr
      FROM control
      GROUP BY curator) c
ORDER BY cs
```